# Modifying <img src style="visibility"> through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a memory game in HTML & JS where you guess 2 different images and try to pick 2 same ones.

I'm stuck with putting an onclick function to a hidden image.

Here is my code so ill try to explain better...

```
var table = '';
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    table += '<tr>';
    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        table += '<td align="center"><img src="./pics/image_part_00' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1) + '.jpg";" width="100px"" onclick="clicked(this);" style="visibility: hidden;"></td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
}
document.getElementById('theGame').innerHTML = '<table border=1 cellpadding="10" class="tabela1">' + table + '</table>'
```

Now what im trying to do is to overwrite that visibility: hidden; so the image is visible when clicked....
And here is the function

```
function clicked(element){
    element.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

but it doesn't work because with that element.style.visibility im changing the visibility of a table cell.

Anyone got a solution? I'm probably missing something and can't figure it...
NOTE: It's a school assignment so it has to be in a table.

Comment: how about putting some blank image initially in td and then onClick change the image's src to the desired one.

Comment: fiddle plz?....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o9fLkax6/
not much to see i'm trying to work out @shyampatil 's answer

Comment: Attach the event to the cell instead of the image. You can't click invisible elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a some fixed javascript. when you catch onclick event, it won't work on hidden elements. So I move event listener onto `td`:

```
var table = '';
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    table += '<tr>';
    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        table += '<td align="center" onclick="click_it(this)">
         <img src="./pics/image_part_00' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1) + '.jpg" 
           width="100px" style="visibility: hidden"></td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
}
document.getElementById('theGame').innerHTML = '<table border=1 cellpadding="10" class="tabela1">' + table + '</table>';

function click_it(cell){
    var image = cell.children[0];
    image.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, this worked :)
But I don't quite understand how cell.children[0] works, does the [0] select first child or?

Comment: yes, sure. children returns array of elements and we need to select first of them. though using jquery it would look more pretty

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the img child of the table cell

```
var child = element.childNodes;
```

The var child will return an array of elements, then you just need to access to the position that the  is, and change the visibility attribute:

```
child[1].style.visibility = "visible";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below,
just played a trick to match element id dynamically
to make it visible.

Added on click to td instead of image.
added id to image.

here is the code

```
<div id="theGame">
```

```
 var table = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

        table += '<td align="center" onclick="clicked(' + j + ')"> <img  id=img_' + j + ' src="./pics/image_part_00' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1) + '.jpg;" width="100px"   style="visibility: hidden;"> </td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
}
document.getElementById('theGame').innerHTML = '<table border=1 cellpadding="10" class="tabela1">' + table + '</table>'

function clicked(element) {
    document.getElementById('img_' + element).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```